# Typescript compiler recreates the whole directory structure for AMD project

Tags: typescript, amd

We have an AMD Typescript project it's directory structure is similar to this:

```
project_root/
 /scripts
   /ts
     module.ts
   /js (generated from the TS files)
 /tests
   /ts
    moduleTest.ts (imports module.ts)
   /js (generated from the TS files)
```

The problem is when we compile a file that imports another module (file) from a directory which isn't a descendant of the importer's directory the TS compiler reconstructs the whole tree from the immediate shared parent of the two directories, into the `js` directory.

So for example, compiling `tests/ts/moduleTest.ts` (that imports `scripts/ts/module.ts`) into the `tests/js` directory, will yield this `tests/js` directory:

```
project_root/tests/js
  /scripts/ts
     module1.js
  /tests/ts
     module1test.js
```

instead of just the `module1test.js` alone in `project_root/tests/js`.
In real life it would even be worse as `module1.ts`would itself import more modules from subdirectories, all of them being created into `project_root/tests/js`.
Apart from importing the generated `.js` files and referncing the corecponding  `.d.ts` files instead of importing `.ts` files. Is there a solution to the creation of the entire tree? Preferably, is there's a way to tell the compiler not to compile imported TS files but only use them as reference?

I've made a basic [example/testing repository](https://github.com/rounds/testTsBuild) to use as a playground. To see what I'm talking about, from the project root, run:

```
tsc --module amd -t ES5 --outDir tests/js/ tests/ts/module1spec.ts
```

This project uses a requireAdapters.d.ts to avoid using relative module names in the import statement (in other words it translates between TS and require.js module names).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a solution to the creation of the entire tree? Preferably, is there's a way to tell the compiler not to compile imported TS files but only use them as reference?

You can use the newly added option `rootDir` See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2772

Comment: Unfortunately, ```rootDir``` expects to include all sources, so in the example it would still have to be ```project_root``` which is what the compiler calculates anyway. It would have worked if I could have specified ```/tests/ts``` as ```rootDir```.

Answer (score 1):

Why not move on from this structure?
Having a js and ts folders sounds like a mistake.
You should have your **scripts** and **tests** folders next to each other, and a **dist** folder that will hold the result javascript files.

This way, you are separating the source-code from the "binary code" (Javascript) same as you would when compiling a C++ into an exe. the **dist** folder will also hold the source maps, and get minified.

This is also good practice for source control, just add your **dist** folder to the .gitignore file.

To sum it up: move to a better structure.